# Grant access to function only for classes that have the same base class

Tags: c++

I have a baseclass, lets call it `base_t`. `base_t` has a function called `void render()`. I want that all classes that derive from `base_t` to have access to that function, but noone else. The render functions will be defined in `base_t` as `virtual void render() = 0;` making it pure virtual.

How can I achieve this in C++? Via friend? Or are there other methods of doing this?

To make it more clear, I want the class `A` (derived from `base_t`) to be able to access the function `render()` in class `B` (also derived from `base_t`) which is implemented by `A` and `B` but is pure virtual defined in `base_t`.

Here is an example:

```
class base_t
{
private:
    virtual void render() = 0;
};

class A : public base_t
{
private:
    virtual void render()
    {
        // Do Stuff
    }
};

class B : public base_t
{
public:
    void dostuff(A *classA)
    {
        // here I want to call render!
        classA->render();
    }

private:
    virtual void render()
    {
        // Do Stuff
    }
};
```

Comment: So make it `protected`?

Comment: Instead of describing code, please show us some example, in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Your clarification is actually making it more confusing to me. If I read it correctly, you first say that A and B are derived from base_t and that both can access the function `render()` that is implemented in base_t (this is achieved by making the function protected as said by @Someprogrammerdude). In the last sentence I read that A and B are both derived from base_t, but B implements the function `render()` that has to be accessible by A.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have edited the question! You see that I want to call the `render` function of `A` inside a function in `B` where `A` is provided via pointer.

Comment: `A` isn't derived from `base_t` in the example, by the way.

Comment: Did you intend to derive A from base_t? Then you forgot to do so ;)

Comment: I should sleep more -.-. Thank you, corrected!

Comment: @Nidhoegger your render() method is also private in class A and you are trying to use it from outside...

Comment: @TheodorBadea that is what I want to achieve. It shall be private, it shall only be usable to classes derived from `base_t`. The code does not work, I know that, but thats what I want to make work. I know this should be possible via `friend`, but Id like to avoid that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about a simple:

```
class base_t
{
private:
    virtual void render() = 0;

protected:
   void renderOther(base_t& other){
      other.render();
   }
};
```

B can render A through the interface method keeping a correct encapsulation.